# How to get "column index" in a gtk.TreeView

Tags: python, treeview, gtk, pygtk, cellrenderer

After hours researching for the answer, I'm finally bent to post my question.

How to get the "column index" of a cell in a gtk.TreeView ?

It exists tens of methods to get the "row index" of any data, but sounds like it exists none to get the "column index", I can't believe it doesn't exist.

Especially, I'm trying to write a handler method which catches the "edited" signal from any gtk.CellRendererText contained in gtk.TreeViewColumn, in order to modify the gtk.ListStore relative to my gtk.TreeView.

I'm writing my code using Python, gtk, and PyGTK.

Thank you in advance for any help and explanations !

Comment: Tree model columns and tree view columns do not match 1:1. Your tree model can store data such as fonts and colors that can be attached to the cell renderers to control how they look. For instance, you could store a font in a column of the tree model and assign that to the `font` attribute in the cell renderer. You will either need to keep track of which GtkTreeViewColumn maps to which model column or write your cell renderer signals separately to make the right change.

Comment: I finally reach this conclusion and behave consequently, thanks for your help!